How to set gtk.ColorButton not to pop up the default color picker
val color_button = Gtk.ColorButton.newWithRgba(color_rgba)


Now I have set the button to the color I want, but when I click it, the default color picker pops up.


val _ = Signal.connect color_button (Gtk.ColorButton.activate false)

The error message shows that activate is not defined
How can I fix and disable it?
